# Amazon MWS Access Denied

Tags: amazon-mws

I am trying to develop an internal app for self use (not to reseller or as a 3rd party developer) using Amazon MWS (not SP-API). I've read (too many) docs about not needing any further credentials for internal app nor not requiring the use of the new SP-API.

My problem is that when I use the scratchpad (https://mws.amazonservices.com/scratchpad/) to test, I get the `AccessDenied` error message: Access to Orders.ListOrders is denied

I am only using the following elements for my auth:

- Seller Id
- Access Key Id (from my Seller Central Account Info)
- Secret Key (from my Seller Central Account Info)

I am successful when using `GetServiceStatus` but I am assuming this API does not require auth. Does anyone have a high-level guide on how to go about creating API calls to Amazon MWS for an internal app?